# Get a row where a string contained php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, string, pdo

I have in my mysql [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXUvm.png).

I need that php (with a PDO Statement) will return every id where email "mrgamer751p@gmail.com" is contained.
I tried with a LIKE statement (only to get rows number):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM market WHERE buyers LIKE :email");
$needle = '%mrgamer751p@gmail.com%';
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $rows;
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: please add your "what I have tried so far" to your questions bod, not inside comments (edit your question). Also instead of showing a screenshot of your table add the ddl  of it so we can play around with it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using concat for wildchar eg:

```
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM market WHERE buyers LIKE concat('%', :email, '%')"); 
 $needle = 'mrgamer751p@gmail.com'; 
 $stmt->bindValue(':email', $needle, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 


foreach ($rows as $key=> $value) {
  echo    $value['your_column_name'].'</br>';
}
```

Comment: Nope, nothing. It doesn't echo nothing

Comment: of course  . ... answer updated  .. you need  loop over the result and echo the column